# Matlab: Find minimum value from a set of values for each column in an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, minimum

I have a 2-D array `A=zeros(1000,1024)`. I want to iteratively compute the difference between each of the value of the i-th row (with i=1-999) and the values of 1000th row.

Right now I think of looping over the 1-999 rows, compute the differences of the current row and the 100th row and store it in a seperaate data structure (`B=zeros(999,1024)`). After, I compute the minimum of each column using another for-loop, which iterates over the columns of `B`.

Do you know of a more efficient, faster approach?

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the minimum of each column, you can save many operations by doing the subtraction at the end:

```
min(A(1:end-1,:),[],1) - A(end,:)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
min(bsxfun(@minus,A(1:999,:),A(1000,:)),[],1)
```

It seems you want to subtract from the last row, so you can make it general -

```
min(bsxfun(@minus,A(1:end-1,:),A(end,:)),[],1)
```

Comment: +1 but I think `min(bsxfun(@minus,A(1:end-1,:),A(end,:)),[],1)` suits the question better

Comment: Do you need the `,[],1`?

Comment: @Dan That's to prevent `min` from working along a row if there's just one row

Comment: @Dan Sort of got into the habit to specify the dimension to avoid confusion.

Comment: @LuisMendo Dan's suggestion works too, but just a safer practice I am trying these days :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic use case for `bsxfun`:

```
M = rand(1000,1024);
V = M(end,:);

MminusV = bsxfun(@minus, M(1:end-1,:), V);

min(MminusV)
```

Comment: My solution was wrong actually as I had included the last row into `bsxfun`. Now its correct but identical to yours :)

Comment: @Divakar but Luis' beats them both ;)